# get proper date in jQuery

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar, date-formatting

I am working on one project and i am using `FullCalendar` and `jQuery dialog.`

I am using `jQuery` dialog because user select any time-slot they will be see one dialog box and inside of that dialog box i will pass start and end time.

But problem is that `fullCalendar` pass `start` argument as date `object` which is `Date {Tue Apr 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}` now problem is that how can just display `02-04-2013 00:00:00` **i do not want to use more plugin** as its already have too much js included.

**What i have?**

**jQuery Dialog code**

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons:
    {
        "Create an event": function()
        {
            var bValid = true;
            if ( bValid )
            {
                //adding event to calendar code
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        Cancel: function()
        {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function()
    {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});
```

**FullCalendar**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
{
    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
        console.log(start);
        $("#dialog-form input#start_time").val(start);
        $("#dialog-form input#end_time").val(end);
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
```

I pasted only half code here because its too long and its not necessary to add it here.

Thanks

Comment: You can try: `$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', start);`. Hope this will give you some idea. PS, This depends on jQ Datepicker.

Comment: @Ronak thanx for reply but its not a datepicker.

Comment: This should help: [Formatting date in JavaScript]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @VimalStan i already seen it but its only output me month date and year not time...see my answer i solved it

Comment: Have you tried: `$.fullCalendar.formatDate( start, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' );`

Comment: @Ronak put that as answer i will accept it....that works too...i wanted easy way and i think that is it...put it as answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate( start, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' );
```

Comment: I've not used fullCalendar in my whole life... :)

Comment: Thanx for quick and perfect solution provided in comment...+1 for u...and accepted it

Comment: so i guess this was the chance to dive into fullCalendar...lol

Answer (score 1):

Well Thanx guys for looking and commenting on question but i found it out.

```
var startDate = start.getFullYear() + "-" + getOtherFiled(start.getMonth()) + "-" + getOtherFiled(start.getDate()) + " " +  getOtherFiled(start.getHours()) + ":" + getOtherFiled(start.getMinutes()) + ":" + getOtherFiled(start.getSeconds());

function getOtherFiled(obj)
{
    if (obj<10)
       return "0"+obj;
    return obj;
}
```

above code successfully output `'2013-03-03 02:30:00'` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

### update

Full calendar has a built in [conversion utility](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/)

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, formatString [, options ] )
```

### Old answer

start is a date object so you can do something as below

```
var curDate = start.getDate();
var curMonth = (parseInt(start.getMonth())+1);
var curYear = start.getFullYear();

alert(curDate+'-'+curMonth+'-'+curYear);
```

here is a [Live fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/c8SLH/).

Comment: getting the time from the date object is just as getting date and year right? `gethours()`, `getMiniutes()`. [Full reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp#gsc.tab=0). btw there is built in utility for full calendar for date conversion.

Comment: ahh I see that in your answer :)